# how could I center a small banner on my header using div tags

Tags: html, css

I'm unable to center a small banner add on the header of my blog. I want it on the center and closer to the button of the header. Probably can be achieved with some style properties, but I can't find it. Here's how it looks now
[pctechtips.org](http://pctechtips.org)

```
<div id="header_add" style="background-color:#000000;height:70px;width:500px;float:center;align:center;">
<a style="color:yellow" href="http://pctechtips.org/contact/"><small>PCtechtips.org</small></a>
<h2 style="color:blue;text-align:center;top-padding:0">Advertise Here!</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to center a div in a div - horizontally?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/114543/how-to-center-a-div-in-a-div-horizontally)

Comment: `float:center` doesn't exist

Answer (score 0):

Set your horizontal margins to auto:

```
<div id="header_add" style="background-color:#000000;height:70px;width:500px;margin:0 auto;">
<a style="color:yellow" href="http://pctechtips.org/contact/"><small>PCtechtips.org</small></a>
<h2 style="color:blue;text-align:center;top-padding:0">Advertise Here!</h2>
</div>
```

Check out the section on auto margins in this article: http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/m/margin/

Comment: margin:0 auto. What the 0 means? and how could I get it closer to the bottom of the header?...

Comment: The 0 means no margins vertically. And what are you looking to get closer to the bottom of the header?

Comment: I just thought it looks better!